# Make git hooks run from current directory

Tags: git, hook, repo

Let's say I have a GIT repo "MyRepo" with a subfolder "Code", like:

```
MyRepo
  |-- .git
        |-- hooks
              |-- pre-commit
        |-- <other stuff>
  |-- Code
        |-- code.java
        |-- <other files>
```

I do `cd MyRepo/Code`, then make some changes, do a `git commit -m "yada yada"`, and then the pre-commit hook runs. Only problem is that it runs in `MyRepo`. I want the pre-commit hook to run in the directory I'm currently in, in this case, `Code`. How can I achieve that?

And as an extension to this question, is there a way to make all of my git hooks behave this way?

Comment: I would think you'd need to pass the current working directory? `echo "$(pwd)"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hooks and aliases are run with your current path inside the work tree passed in as the `GIT_PREFIX` variable, so your hook can either `cd $GIT_PREFIX` or append it as desired.

. . . I see this is not documented except in some release notes from long ago, I found it by reasoning something like it had to be there and putting a `declare -p ${!GIT_*}` in a hook, running it from a subdir, then checking the Git history for the `GIT_` var that had that.

Comment: This *is* documented in [githooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) now, in the "description" section, plus in [git-config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) where it mentions `GIT_PREFIX`, but it's not all put together very well. (Or maybe at all, really. Aliases are special after all. It's just that they're not quite *that* special after all. :-) )

Comment: @torek hunh. I did `git grep GIT_PREFIX` on my 2.35+ checkout and got only the alias docs and the 1.7.6 relnotes, nothing in hooks. Looked again, still nothing . . . and I don't see GIT_PREFIX at your link, am I blind?

Comment: It's under `alias.*`: `If the alias expansion is prefixed with an exclamation point, it will be treated as a shell command. For example, defining alias.new = !gitk --all --not ORIG_HEAD, the invocation git new is equivalent to running the shell command gitk --all --not ORIG_HEAD. Note that shell commands will be executed from the top-level directory of a repository, which may not necessarily be the current directory. GIT_PREFIX is set as returned by running git rev-parse --show-prefix from the original current directory. See git-rev-parse[1].`

Comment: In the source, it's in `Documentation/config/alias.txt`. Should show up with `git grep`; it does for me.

Comment: @torek I don't think many people will expect behavior documented for alias execution to also apply to hooks. And the word "alias", like `GIT_PREFIX` does not appear in the hooks docs anywhere I can see.

Comment: That's why I added the "(Or maybe at all, really)" part.